# Redis primary and secondary key

Tags: node.js, redis, nosql

I am very new to nosql REDIS and need to create a structure similar to this.
Key1- Vehicle ,
Key2 - Color ,
Subkey - Type (can be electric , petrol , diesel)
I should be able to fetch with the combination 
  **key1 , key2** OR **key1 , key2 and with Subtype**
How can I obtain this using Redis. Can anyone pls help ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redis is a memeory based key-value database.
That means you cannot make complicate queries.
What you can do is store complicate data under one key.
For instance tou can convert your object into ByteArray and store it under spesific key (maybe even convert to protobuf)

What you can do is query multiple keys in single query. Check the MGET command:
https://redis.io/commands/mget

For storing complicated structures under a key please check Redis JSON module:
https://redislabs.com/blog/redis-as-a-json-store/
NOTE: this does not mead you can query based on attributes stored in the value

feel free to be more spesific about your use-case and maybe i'll be able to help you to design an appropriate key-value structure